Could not find gem 'wdm (~> 0.1.1) mingw, x64_mingw, mswin' in locally installed gems. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
I am new to Jekyll. I tried to start a Jekyll project but wdm didn't install. While trying to run the local server on my machine with bundle exec jekyll serve I got the following error:
C:/Ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.17/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:345:in `raise_not_found!': Could not find gem 'wdm (~> 0.1.1) mingw, x64_mingw, mswin' in locally installed gems. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from C:/Ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.17/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:423:in `block in prepare_dependencies'
        from C:/Ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.17/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:401:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.17/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:401:in `map'
        from C:/Ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.17/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:401:in `prepare_dependencies'
        from C:/Ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.17/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:63:in `setup_solver'
        from C:/Ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.17/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:28:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.17/lib/bundler/definition.rb:635:in `start_resolution'
        from C:/Ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.17/lib/bundler/definition.rb:305:in `resolve'
        from C:/Ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.17/lib/bundler/definition.rb:584:in `materialize'
        from C:/Ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.17/lib/bundler/definition.rb:193:in `specs'
        from C:/Ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.17/lib/bundler/definition.rb:259:in `specs_for'
        from C:/Ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:18:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.17/lib/bundler.rb:164:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:52:in `require_from_bundler'
        from C:/Ruby33/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/exe/jekyll:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby33/bin/jekyll:32:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby33/bin/jekyll:32:in `<main>'

I want to share that, I installed rubyinstaller-devkit-3.3.4-1-x86. Here's my environment setup:
ruby - 3.3.4,
gem -3.5.11,
Bundler version 2.5.17
While creating the project, I noticed an error while installing wdn.
So, what should I do now!?

You have to try gem install wdm and look at the output to determine what went wrong with the installation. Probably there's a library missing you have to install before the gem will build.

make sure that you're running the ruby you think you are. On my system /usr/bin/ruby was not the one compatible with mingw64; had to put /mingw64/bin first in my $PATH. Then wdm installed fine.

@MarkReed  It works fine now. The issue was the mismatching of wdm version. Now, it works nicely
